# Keyboard shortcut to open new Instant Messages in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I just installed Ubuntu 10.04. I am using the default IM client (Empathy I believe). How can I  open new IM messages with just the keyboard? I despise having to click on the green envelope icon, select chat and then select the contact name. I want to just do this by pressing some keys to bring up to the foreground the IM window with the message?

Some people have suggested to leave open a conversation and then do alt+tab and then switch to the tab with the new message but I do not like to leave windows open and I also I feel like it's too slow to do all those steps.

Answer (score 0):

If D-Bus can be used to tell Empathy to open the window then you can use a custom keyboard shortcut bound to `dbus-send` to send the appropriate message.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the question is: how can I use dbus to to open the  Empathy window that of a new incoming message :)